# Reading command line arguments

Tags: c

I am trying to read a command line argument that looks like this

./program -aB -v

But I can not seem to understand how I can read the -aB command.

I have tried putting aB in my switch but it did not work.
This is the code I have that worked.

```
void processCommandSwitches(int argc, char *argv[], char **ppszFileWidgets, Simulation sim){

 int i;

    // Examine each of the command arguments other than the name of the program.
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {

        switch (argv[i][1])
        {
        case 'v':                  

                sim->bVerbose = TRUE;

            break;
        case '?':
            *ppszFileWidgets = argv[i];
            break;
        default:
            *ppszFileWidgets = argv[i];
        }
         *ppszFileWidgets = argv[i];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switching on the second character (which only works for single letters), how about try using `strcmp(const char *lhs, const char *rhs)` which returns 0 (equal), positive (lhs after rhs), or negative (lhs before rhs)?

E.g.:

```
#include <string.h>
// ....
for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
  if (strcmp(argv[i], "-v") == 0) {
    // ...
  }
  else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-aB") == 0) {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```